# core data one-to-many save duplicate row with nil

Tags: ios, swift, core-data

I have simple save function where I save new parent item with one child item. But my problem is that function add two row (one is duplicate with nil value) to core data child table? Row in sqllite (core data) one is correct, but why create second with nil???

rightly should save only one row to child table.

- XCODE 7.1
- IOS target 9.1

my function and other (embedded images)

[image]

> SQL debug log:
>
> BEGIN EXCLUSIVE   INSERT INTO ZGROUPDATA(Z_PK, Z_ENT, Z_OPT, ZNAME)
>   VALUES(?, ?, ?, ?)   INSERT INTO ZGROUPITEM(Z_PK, Z_ENT, Z_OPT,
>   ZITEMTOGROUP, Z_FOK_ITEMTOGROUP, ZHOST) VALUES(?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)
>   **INSERT INTO ZGROUPITEM(Z_PK, Z_ENT, Z_OPT, ZITEMTOGROUP, Z_FOK_ITEMTOGROUP, ZHOST) VALUES(?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)**   COMMIT
>
> **I add ONE item but in coredata save two**

Comment: If you use Core Data to fetch your parent object, how many child objects does it have?

Comment: only one. with Z_PK = 1 . But table increases unnecessarily. If i delete parentObject (delete rule Cascade) automatic delete child object but row with nil is remains in table

Comment: Is there any other place in your code where a GroupItem could be added to the context?  I added code like your `saveData` to a new test project and got only one object per table.

Comment: @PhillipMills you are right! I went through the code and you're right. Thank you very much